# How to add both public and private api key in android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

I gave the command in the `@GET` method like `/v1/public/characters?apikey='my_public_api_key'`. Now whenever I run this command on browser, it give me an error like {`"code":"MissingParameter","message":"You must provide a hash."}` . Can please someone answer this for me?

**I am using the marvel developer api**